# How to return Exceptions in Nest js

Tags: nestjs

I am new to Nest js and I wonder what the best place to return your exceptions and success responses is it from the controller or from a service. This is what I have implemented and I want to know what will be the best practice to handle and send API responses to the client. Shall I return every success and error responses from the controller or from the service?

Controller:

```
@Post('sign-up')
@HttpCode(200)
async signUp(@Body() request: ISignUpDto) {
   const user = await this._authService.createUser(request);
   console.log(user);
   const otpLength = user.otp.toString().length;

   return {
      message: `We've e-mailed you a ${otpLength} digit OTP. Please check your e-mail and complete the verification.`,
      dataset: null,
   };
}
```

Service:

```
public async createUser(request: ISignUpDto): Promise<User> {
  const isUserExist = await this.isUserExist(request.email);
     if (isUserExist) {
         throw new BadRequestException({
           dataset: null,
           message: 'The provided e-mail is already in use by an existing user.',
      });
  } else {
            const hashedPassword = await hashPassword(request.password);
            const user = await this._prisma.user.create({
                data: {
                    active: false,
                    otp: generateOTP(6),
                    email: request.email,
                    password: hashedPassword,
                    firstName: request.firstName,
                    lastName: request.lastName,
                    gender: request.gender ? request.gender : null,
                    dateOfBirth: request.dateOfBirth
                        ? request.dateOfBirth
                        : null,
                },
                select: {
                    id: true,
                    email: true,
                    firstName: true,
                    lastName: true,
                    gender: true,
                    dateOfBirth: true,
                    otp: true,
                    active: true,
                    createdAt: true,
                },
            });

            await this.sendSignUpVerificationEmail(user.email);

            return user as User;
        }
    }
```

Comment: you don't _return_ exceptions. You should raise them via `throw` to let nestjs handle them for you (or catch them with [exception filters](https://docs.nestjs.com/exception-filters))

Comment: @MicaelLevi, what is the right place to raise them, in the controller or in the service?

Comment: that's up to you. Also, I don't think is good to raise transport-specific erros on services (like `BadRequestException`)

Comment: @MicaelLevi, can you please explain `transport-specific errors`? I have seen a lot of tutorials where they raise errors in service. Please suggest a good and alternative approach.

Comment: yeah those tutorials aren't that good. I didn't find any real good boilerplate for nestjs yet :/ [`BadRequestException` is for HTTP](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/blob/79cccd05745834589fca85003d39d253144c15e7/packages/common/exceptions/bad-request.exception.ts#L11), that's why I said it is transport-specific. Which means that reusing those services in another context could be a bit hard, I guess